# How to write to Kinesis stream from Spark3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

How do I write to a Kinesis stream from Spark3? We were previously doing this in Spark 2.4.0 while using the DataSourceV2 class and related classes/APIs as a way to connect - wondering what the corresponding classes would be in Spark3+?

I see classes like Table/TableProvider - wondering if this supports writing to Kinesis? Documentation for doing something like this seems to be lacking in general online, wondering if anyone either knows whether this is possible, and if so, if they could point to any code examples.